# How to execute multiple commands in the while loop condition?

Tags: bash, while-loop

I want to create a directory with increasing numbers every time I run the script. My current solution is:

```
COUNTER=1
while mkdir $COUNTER; (( $? != 0 ))
do
     COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1)) 
done
```

Is separating the commands in the while condition with a `;`(semicolon) the best practice?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve/do? create directories which is what your code does  and what else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very *purpose* of `while` and the shell's other control statements is to run a command and examine its exit code. You can use `!` to negate the exit code.

```
while ! mkdir "$COUNTER"
do
     COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1)) 
done
```

Notice also the [quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable); see further [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

As such, if you want two commands to run and only care about the exit code from the second, a semicolon is the correct separator. Often, you want both commands to succeed; then, `&&` is the correct separator to use.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to test the exit status, just check if the directory exists already and increment. Here is one way

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

counter=1
while [[ -e $counter ]]; do
  ((counter++))
done


if ! mkdir "$counter"; then  ##: mkdir failed
  echo failed                ##: execute this code
fi
```

POSIX sh shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

counter=1
while [ -e "$counter" ]; do
  counter=$((counter+1))
done

if ! mkdir "$counter"; then  ##: If mkdir failed
  echo failed                ##: Execute this code
fi
```

- The bang `!` negates the exit status of mkdir.
- See `help test | grep '^[[:blank:]]*!'`

Well if you're just going to negate the exit status of `mkdir` inside the while loop then you might as well use `until`, which is the opposite of `while`

```
counter=1
until mkdir "$COUNTER"; do
  :
  COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
done
```

Comment: Thanks, still I would like to know what would be the best practice in case I ever need several commands in the condition.